# Better way to return count rather than using globals

Tags: python, dns, spf

I have the following code (using dnspython), which works - but it uses globals which I'm not keen on. I was thinking that I could use a recursive function but there is no obvious end.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be improved??

```
import dns.resolver

dns_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
dns_resolver.nameservers = ['1.1.1.1', '1.0.0.1']

resolve_count = 0


def get_spf_count(domain_name):
    global resolve_count

    for answer in dns_resolver.query(domain_name, 'TXT'):
        spf = answer.to_text() if 'v=spf1' in answer.to_text() else None

        if spf:
            spf_records = [
                record
                for record in spf.replace('" "', '').replace('"', '').split()
                if record not in ['v=spf1', '~all', '-all', '+all', '?all']
            ]
            for record in spf_records:
                if 'include:' in record:
                    check_domain = record.split(':')[1]
                    get_spf_count(check_domain)
                    resolve_count += 1
                elif record.startswith(('a:', 'mx:', 'ptr:', 'exists:')):
                    resolve_count += 1

get_spf_count('google.com')
print(resolve_count)
```

Comment: Your second point is unrelated to the first question - on this site, multiple questions require multiple posts. Also, have you considered wrapping your code in a class? That way your global variables can instead be instance variables.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return `resolve_count` as a function return?

Comment: The function only needs to know how many lookups *it* made. Have the caller add the result to their tally each time they call us.

Comment: @RandomDavis - this wasn't a question, more of a comment (thus why the ...) - I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly cleaned-up recursive function with a properly local variable.

```
import dns.resolver


def get_spf_count(domain_name, dns_resolver=None):
    if dns_resolver is None:
        dns_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        dns_resolver.nameservers = ['1.1.1.1', '1.0.0.1']

    resolve_count = 0

    for answer in dns_resolver.query(domain_name, 'TXT'):
        spf = answer.to_text() if 'v=spf1' in answer.to_text() else None

        if spf:
            spf_records = [
                record
                for record in spf.replace('" "', '').replace('"', '').split()
                if record not in ['v=spf1', '~all', '-all', '+all', '?all']
            ]
            for record in spf_records:
                if 'include:' in record:
                    check_domain = record.split(':')[1]
                    resolve_count += 1 + get_spf_count(check_domain, dns_resolver)
                elif record.startswith(('a:', 'mx:', 'ptr:', 'exists:')):
                    resolve_count += 1

    return resolve_count


print(get_spf_count('google.com'))
```

Notice how everything the function needs is local within the function, including the `dns.resolver.Resolver()` object (and how you could pass in a shared resolver object if you wanted to).

Comment: This works perfectly :) now all I need to do is add some functionality to check if we already know about it and this will be stupidly useful :)

Comment: Maybe tighten up the SPF parsing if you really want to develop this into something like production code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass `resolve_count` in as a variable, and have the function return the updated value?

```
def get_spf_count(domain_name, resolve_count):
    for answer in dns_resolver.query(domain_name, 'TXT'):
        spf = answer.to_text() if 'v=spf1' in answer.to_text() else None
        if spf:
            spf_records = [
                record
                for record in spf.replace('" "', '').replace('"', '').split()
                if record not in ['v=spf1', '~all', '-all', '+all', '?all']
            ]
            for record in spf_records:
                if 'include:' in record:
                    check_domain = record.split(':')[1]
                    get_spf_count(check_domain, resolve_count)
                    resolve_count += 1
                elif record.startswith(('a:', 'mx:', 'ptr:', 'exists:')):
                    resolve_count += 1

    return resolve_count    


resolve_count = get_spf_count('google.com', 0)
print(resolve_count)
```

Comment: You fail to pass in the value when the function recurses.

Comment: Thanks, tripleee!  Fixed.